# Automorphism of $\mathbb{H}$ uniquely determined by a point of $\mathbb{H}$ and a point of $\partial \mathbb{H}$

Tags: complex-analysis, group-actions, riemann-surfaces, automorphism-group

I'm reading some lecture notes on complex analysis, where the following is stated:

> An element of $\textrm{Aut}(\mathbb{H})$ is uniquely determined by the image of a point in $\mathbb{H}$ and of a point in $\partial \mathbb{H}$ (where the action of this group is extended by continuity).

As far as I know, $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{H}) = \mathrm{PSL}(2, \mathbb{R})$, acting by homography, $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \cdot z = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}.$$However, if I take $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{3}{2} & -\frac{1}{4} \\ 1 & -\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix},$$then this automorphism isn't well-defined at $\frac{1}{2}$!

> My question: Is there a way to recover this statement, or is it just wrong? For example, does adding a point at infinity help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: consider $\mathbb{H}\subset \mathbb{S}$ in the Riemann sphere. What is $\partial\mathbb{H}?$ In this situation, what is the image of $\frac12$ in your example?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "adding a point at infinity". If $\mathbb{S} = \mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$, then the image is $\infty$, right?

Comment: If we indeed do consider $\mathbb{H} \subset \mathbb{S}$, could you also give me a hint about how to prove the statement (i.e. an automorphism of $\mathbb{H}$ is uniquely determined by a pt on the interior and a pt on the boundary)? Is it just a big calculation, or is there an elegant solution? I've been doing calculations for the past hour, and it becomes a horrible mess pretty quickly.
Needless to say, since you answered my question, I've accepted your answer. I'm just asking this in case you're willing to help me even more :-P.

Comment: Consider two automorphisms $f_1,f_2$ satisfying your hypotesis, and define $g:=f_1\circ f_2^{-1}$.This automorphism fixes two points, one inside $\mathbb{H}$ and one on the boundary. Can you prove that $g=z$?

Comment: I tried, but I can't seem to figure it out. My attempt involved the Schwarz lemma (I switched to the unit disk) - however, once I pre- and post-compose $g$ so that $g(0) = 0$, I get that $g$ fixes $0$ and some point in $S^1$, which doesn't help me much.

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic you are almost there: recall that every automorphism in $\mathbb{D}$ has the form $\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}e^{i\vartheta}$. Your automorphism fixes $0$ (and thus $a=0$) and it fixes a point on the unit circle. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yep, it was easy! Thanks! I was so obsessed with trying to apply the part of the Schwarz lemma which implies that $f(z) = az$ that I completely forgot to just plug the values in!